# Access Sub Component Parameters from Parent

Tags: typescript, angular2-forms

I have the following code

```
<div  class="data-container" #dataContainer>
<result (click)="onContainerClick($event, i)" *ngFor="let result of resultItems; let  i = index" [result]="result" [index]="i"></result>
```

Each result has a parameter
  closed: boolean;

How can i access from the parent in the TS code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.
.
.
import { ViewChildren, QueryList, AfterViewInit } from @angular/core
.
.
.
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChildren(ResultComponent) resultComps: QueryList<ResultComponent>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.resultComponents.forEach((comp: ResultComponent) => console.log(comp.closed));
    }
}
```

Comment: it supposed to be an array, it's undefined after i did so.